# Lldb and OSX crashReports

Tags: osx-mavericks, lldb

People,

I have just working on OSX 10.9, and have a crash at hand to debug.
I see OSX has LLVM and LLDB which replaces well known and well documented gdb.

Anyway, I see in crashreport the precise stack trace, and that's pretty impressive from Apple.
However, I can get to image lookup in lldb and print the API name.
When I use verbose option with image lookup it prints few extra information, however, I am still not able to view local variables in the specific API.
I tried image dump, image sym-tab etc and other lldb options.
None of them seems to helping. Scanned through StackOverflow to see if its there's but not luck yet.

Therefore I have the Q
From OSX crashreports we cannot get stack-trace with local variables/arguments values?
How do we see a function arguments/locals variables using LLDB when we a OSX crashreport handy.

I see frame variable etc works fine when attaching to a running process, however these doesn't work when I crash the process and try to see the locals/arguments.

Request you to please guide.
THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CrashReporter output consists (mainly) of a backtrace of all the threads in the program, the list of libraries/frameworks that were loaded at the time (with their load addresses and Mach-O UUIDs to identify which build of each binary was being used) and the register context for the frame that crashed.

`image lookup -va` in lldb will show you where the arguments/variables were located at that given pc.  If a variable is stored in register rbx at that point, `image lookup` will say it's in rbx.  Often times a variable is stored on the stack and the location will say something like `rbp-40` where rbp is the frame pointer register on x86_64.  In that case, it means the variable is currently available on the stack at the value of rbp minus 40.

Crash reports do not include any of the stack contents -- they intentionally don't include things that might be sensitive.  For instance, your program might have a password in plaintext in a stack local variable.

If a variable you're interested in is stored in a register at the point of the crash, you can use the register context section of the crash report to figure out what value was in there.

Often it's not quite that simple.  If you can read your way through assembly language, the best way to figure out what really happened is to disassemble the crashed function and use the register context information to understand why the final instruction resulted in the crash.